# configure router.beforeEach

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex

I try to get back the user on the homepage when he(it) clicks the arrow to return the previous page of the browser.

when I am on the page login I cannot go back with the arrows of the browser.

We advised me to use " to route BeforeEach " I do not understand how it works.

**main.js:**

```
    Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'Register',
      component: Register,
    },
    {
      path: '/complete_registration',
      name: 'Complete Registration',
      component: CompleteRegistration,
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Profile',
      component: Profile,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({routes, mode: 'history'})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  if ( from.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth) ) {
    alert('enter')
    next('/');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

By connecting me it shows me in a loop pop-up of alert

Comment: Why does the login route requires auth ? and why are you checking wether the from route needs auth? Shouldn't it be the to route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas Kleßen is totally right in his comment:

1. You should add `meta: { requiresAuth: true }` only to the routes that need the user to be authenticated. It is not the case of the login page (nor the Register and Home ones I guess).
2. In `router.beforeEach()` you should check if the "target" needs the user to be authenticated, i.e. the `to` (and not the `from`, which corresponds to the page you are coming from).

However you need to add an extra check: if the user is not authenticated you need to redirect her/him to the login page. For that you can use `firebase.auth().currentUser`, as follows. See the corresponding Firebase doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentUser).

```
const routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'Register',
      component: Register
    },
    {
      path: '/complete_registration',
      name: 'Complete Registration',
      component: CompleteRegistration
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Profile',
      component: Profile,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    },
    {
      path: '/otherProtectedPage',
      name: 'OtherProtectedPage',
      component: OtherProtectedPage,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({routes, mode: 'history'})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record  => record.meta.requiresAuth)
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser

    if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
        next('/login')
    } else if (requiresAuth && currentUser) {
        next()
    } else {
        next()
    }
})
```